# What is the difference between "have to do", "have to have done", "had to do" and "had to have done"?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, perfect-infinitive

Could you tell what is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> To get a place at the college, you **have to pass** the exams.
>
> To get a place at the college, you **have to have  passed** the exams.
>
> To get a place at the college, you **had to pass** the exams.
>
> To get a place at the college, you **had to have passed** the exams.

Answer (score 0):

perfect infinitive means one tense earlier than the main verb tense.

You have to pass (now)

You had to pass (past)

You have to have passed (should have passed before now, i.e., in the past)- have to (present)- have passed(in the past)

You had to have passed (should have passed before in the past, i.e., in the distant past)- had to(past) - have passed(in the distant past).

I lost a watch that I had bought yesterday.
You lost (past), had bought(distant past: great past)

It seems to be true=It seems that it is true

It seems to have been true=It seems that it was true

One tense ealier than the main verb tense if you use "to+have+pp"

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you clearify something? You said the second sentence means it that you should have passed by now, and the third means that should have happened in the past. Does that mean that the second and the third sentence means the person didn't pass?

Comment: You seemed to understand: It seemed that you understood. You seemed to have understood: It seemed that you had understood.

Comment: _You have to have passed_ means, in effect, that you need an exam certificate to show to the college authorities. _You had to pass/ have passed_ refer to the situation in the past (maybe when the entrance requirements were different).

Comment: Brandon: I'm sorry, but does your comment mean I'm right?

Comment: Kate Bunting: Thanks for your comment, but do you mean that there is no difference in meaning between the first and the second and the third and the fourth?

Comment: It was just another example for your understanding.

Comment: There is only a slight difference between the pairs. In the 2nd and 4th there is an unspoken *already* after the word *you*. The date of the exam is pushed further into the past. A friend to whom you address these sentences might reply to the first, 'And will you?' To the 2nd, 'And have you?' To the 3rd, 'And did you?' To the 4th, 'And had you?'

Comment: In effect, there is no difference in meaning. One refers to the necessity of taking the exam first (and being successful), the other to the necessity of showing that you have already passed it.